# Error: Unknown type 'ContentPage' in XML namespace 'http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms' MyAPP!!!!!!!.UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyAPP_______.UWP"
             x:Class="MyAPP_______.UWP.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Outputs 3 errors, I wanted to test the work of xamarin, and the emulator, I don't know what to do, I'm working with xamarin for the first time.

1.Unknown type 'ContentPage' in XML namespace 'http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms'   MyAPP!!!!!!!.UWP
2.  Unknown type 'Label' in XML namespace 'http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms'   MyAPP!!!!!!!.UWP
3.Unknown type 'StackLayout' in XML namespace 'http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms'   MyAPP!!!!!!!.UWP

Comment: @OneCricketeer that's how he translates, you can still read in your English

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows

Comment: Did you  create  using the Add New Item -> Forms Xaml Page?And did  the projects that reference the shared project have a reference to Xamarin.Forms nuget package/component?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, I created the wrong project initially, read the documentation and noticed that I did not create an empty project, and decided to re-create and now everything is as it should be.